# Cannot locate hover/onmouseover css change

Tags: javascript, css, joomla1.5

I'm working on a Joomla template, I've changed the top level menu colors to match our logo but I'm having trouble locating where the change in color is coming from when you mouse over the dropdown menu. I set the top level menu item to hover using firebug so it stays open though when I inspect the drop down elements I cannot see from where the color change is coming from. I've set hover states on each subsequent div and li and that did not trigger the change in color so I'm baffled as to where the color change comes from. This is the webpage I'm working on http://www.webchild.com.au/search-results

Answer (score 0):

You have a Javascript updating the color for the class hover-box1, check that...

Comment: The color at line 32 in bluegrey.css changes the top level menu hover color but not the dropdown.

Comment: @user1467850 OK I think you should be looking for a javascript that changes the bg color for the class hover-box...

Comment: @user1467850 great, I updated my suggested answer, please check as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I think it your case menu backgroud color is  an image located here:

http://www.webchild.com.au/templates/yoo_mellow_July2012_Wider/css/variations/../../images/variations/bluegrey/menu_level1_item.png

Comment: I was able to change the top level menu background colors by locating them in bluegrey.css and editing the images it pulls through for the sides, however the dropdown menu doesn't seem to rely on the same styles and it is the one I am having troubles locating.

Comment: I see that javascript is dynamically changing inline style. This seems to be a commercial component, so you must have some administrator management where you can change the color.

Comment: Yeah on the admin end it lets me choose between predefined color combos but not individual colors. Luckily I just located the .js file that calls the color changes so I think I've found my answer!

Comment: Did you check template settings too?